# In Sheets how do I have a cell confirm a specific user has completed a specific activity as populated on a sheet from google forms?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google form that populates a row with answers including User and Activity.  I have 75 users and 63 activities to check.  On a second tab I have a column of users and a header row of activities.  I would like this second tab to populate a cell green with "0" if it finds both the user and the activity on the form.  I would like it top populate red with a "1" if it is not complete.  This allows for a rapid check on what activities the user has completed and provide a way for me to also total up the number of activities remaining for any user or any activity as well.

The user is in column C on the form response and the activity is in column D.

[[image]][image]

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]!   Please [Edit] your question to include sample data as text.  Convert copied cells/tables from Sheets to [proper markdown format](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables). Tools like the [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) can make this easier.  Include relevant formulas describing what did/didn't work and any errors you encountered.

Answer (score 0):

```
=BYROW(TOCOL(A2:A,1), LAMBDA(u, 
   BYCOL(TOROW(B1:1,1), LAMBDA(a,
   --NOT(COUNTA(IFERROR(
     FILTER(form!C:C,(form!C:C=u)*(form!D:D=a)))))))))
```

<sub>**Calculation Sheet**</sub>
[image]

<sub>**Form Results Sheet**</sub>
[image]

<sub>**Conditional Format Rules**</sub>
[image]

<sub>**Detailed Rule**</sub>
[image]